# Mapbox how to write layer paint property with stops so that it can support feature-state?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using mapbox gl js 0.46.0. I took an advantage of setFeatureState API(>=0.46.0) which has a much better performance for "hovering upon a feature" like use cases.

I have decided to use a single layer for a feature having two states, one is "none" and other is "selected". Unfortunately, because of inadequate documentation and examples, I am not able to fully sync up the visuals for these two states.

For example, if I wanted to have a line-width property with stops based upon zoom levels, how do I write this kind of expression for corresponding "selected" and "none" state?

```
 "paint": {
            "line-color": [
                "match",[ "string", [ "feature-state", "line_color" ], "none" ],
                    "selected", "hsl(189, 87%, 37%)",
                    "none", "hsl(189, 87%, 37%)",
                    "hsl(189, 87%, 37%)"
                ],
            "line-width":  [
                "match",[ "string", [ "feature-state", "line_width" ], "none" ],
                    "selected", 4,
                    "none", 3,
                    3
                ],
            "line-opacity": [
                "match",[ "string", [ "feature-state", "line_opacity" ], "none" ],
                    "selected", 0.68,
                    "none", 0.38,
                    0.38
                ]
        }
```